# Acceder a $ref desde otro componente en VUE / VUEX

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Estoy implementado `vue2-google-maps` en mi proyecto y quiero acceder a las `$ref` de otro componente.

**Vista padre**

```html
<template>
  <div class="home">
      <Header/>
      <div class="container-fluid">
         <div class="row">
            <Mapa />
            <Sidebar/>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

**Mapa**

```html
<template>
<div>
            <GmapMap
                ref="mapRef" 
                :center="centro"
                :zoom="zoom"
                :options="opciones"
                map-type-id="roadmap"
                style="width: 100%; height: 90vh"
                disableDefaultUI: true
                @click="mapClick"
            >       
            </GmapMap>     
</div>

<script>
export default {
    name:"Mapa",
    data(){
        return{
            map: null,
         }
    },
    mounted(){
        //Aqui es como accedo a la $ref del mapa
        this.$refs.mapRef.$mapPromise.then((map) => { 
            this.map = map
        })
    }
}
</script>
```

Hasta aquí todo bien pero al momento de querer acceder a **$ref** de  desde el componente `<Sidebar/>` me retorna `undefined` lo que es normal ya que el elemento no ese encuentra en este componente..

La pregunta es como puedo acceder  desde `<Sidebar/>` a `$refs.mapRef.` que esta declarado en `<Mapa/>`

Comment: Puedes darme un poco de contexto del ¿por qué necesitas hacer esto? tengo una idea en mente que puede funcionar pero, veremos si hay algo mejor que hacer

Comment: Es por que los botones y acciones se encuentran en otro componente. por ejemplo fijar coordenadas ,  obtener zoom actual , crear mark

Comment: Bien, entonces tienes, por ejemplo, un botón en `<sidebar />` qué debería hacer "cierta" acción sobre el **mapa** que está en `<Mapa />`. ¿Es correcto?